# Unexpected resource type 'dimen' expected: string

Tags: android, android-studio, resources, build.gradle

I updated to API 33 and now there is an error in the designer "*unexpected resource type 'dimen' expected: string*". This error does not affect anything, but I would like to remove it.

This error appeared when I changed `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` from version `32` to version `33`. (`minSdkVersion` uses version `24`).

[image]

Resource file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

1. For the sake of experimentation, I tried changing `dimen` to `string` and it worked, but obviously it shouldn't be that type as Android Studio requests localization for other languages.
2. I also tried to lower the API version and it helped.
3. Also, I decided to create a new text project based on API 33 and there was the same error there too.

Comment: Adding this to the xml file doesn't work either? android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

Comment: @MennoSpijker Everything works fine. It's just that the error is highlighted in the designer itself, and there are no errors in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today there was an update for Android Studio and this bug has been fixed.

Comment: it does not work on Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Beta 3. Which version I need to use.

Comment: I have installed the latest version that is available today. (not beta).